# Change dtypes in Pandas DataFrame cell-by-cell

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:**

I have a Pandas.DataFrame which stores only unicode values. Each column contains values that could be converted to either an integer or float, or left as unicode. (Python version 2.7.15, Pandas version 0.23.0)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[u'1', u'1.23', u'', u'foo_text'], 'y':[u'bar_text', u'', u'2', u'4.56']})
print df
          x         y
0         1  bar_text
1      1.23
2                   2
3  foo_text      4.56
```

I would like to convert the type of each cell as follows:

1. If possible to convert to int, convert to int
2. Else if possible to convert to float, convert to float
3. Else, leave as unicode

**Solution attempts:**

The following code does precisely what I want:

```
type_list = [int, float, unicode]
for column in df.columns:
    for index in df.index:
        for desired_type in type_list:
            try:
                df.loc[index,column] = desired_type(df.loc[index,column])
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

The problem is that my actual DataFrame is >10 million cells, and this will way too long to execute. I am trying to find a faster way to do this.

I have looked at `pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects()`, and `pandas.to_numeric()`, but neither appear to handle the case of mixed types within a column.

Comment: it would better to create 3 new columns for each `x`, `y`, so that you end up with `x_int`, `x_float`, `x_str` and structure subsequent code accordingly.

Comment: At the end of the day the number of columns and their names must be unchanged. Are you suggesting this as an intermediate step?

Comment: Python version 2.7.15, Pandas version 0.23.0 (updated question)

Comment: no, i'm suggesting having multiple types in 1 column is indicative of bad logic, and that it would better to separate the types into their own columns

Comment: @haleemur-ali I agree with but, unfortunately I need to keep the data mixed in the original columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a function along with `.apply()` which will be a lot faster than three nested for-loops.

So something like:

```
def change_dtype(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            return value

for column in df.columns:
    df.loc[:, column] = df[column].apply(change_dtype)
```